# Remove Delete Icon From One2many Field on condtion Base(Odoo 11)

Tags: odoo-11

I want to remove the delete icon in Odoo for some line in the one2many field where the Boolean field is True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable default delete button, then create your own delete button and apply your condition on it:

```
<tree string="My Tree" delete="false">
    <field name="my_field1"/>
    <field name="my_field2"/>
    <field name="my_boolean_field"/>
    <button name="unlink"
            string="Unlink"
            type="object"
            class="btn-secondary"
            attrs="{'invisible': [('my_boolean_field', '=', False)]}"
            icon="fa-trash-o"/>
</tree>
```